# Python: For statement to display a list with specific strings?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I'm new to Python and trying to learn to use a for statement to display information in a certain way.... Is there a way to use the for statement to display a list like this?

```
w = "Fa1/1                           connected    42         a-full  a-100 10/100BaseTX"
v = w.split()

x=v[0]
print "Port ", x 

y=v[1]
print "Status ", y 

z=v[2]
print "VLAN ", z 

a=v[3]
print "Duplex ", a 

b=v[4]
print "Speed ", b 

c=v[5]
print "Type ", c 

-------------------------
Port  Fa1/1
Status  connected
VLAN  42
Duplex  a-full
Speed  a-100
Type  10/100BaseTX
```

I have tried a lot of different methods but keep getting value and index errors....

Thanks for any help....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> w = "Fa1/1                           connected    42         a-full  a-100 10/100BaseTX"
>>> firstList = ['Port', 'Status', 'VLAN', 'Duplex', 'Speed', 'Type']
>>> testList = zip(firstList, w.split())
>>> for a, b in testList:
        print a, b


Port Fa1/1
Status connected
VLAN 42
Duplex a-full
Speed a-100
Type 10/100BaseTX
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean, like this?

```
w = 'Fa1/1                    connected    42         a-full  a-100 10/100BaseTX'
f = 'Port {0}\nStatus {1}\nVLAN {2}\nDuplex {3}\nSpeed {4}\nType {5}\n'
s = f.format(*w.split())

print s

Port Fa1/1
Status connected
VLAN 42
Duplex a-full
Speed a-100
Type 10/100BaseTX
```

In this case using a [format string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) is simpler than explicitly iterating over the results returned by `split()`.

Comment: @JustinParker And it's shorter and more flexible ;)